# Proper way to catch imagemagick convert errors in php exec

Tags: php, error-handling, imagemagick

Hi guys whats the proper way to catch imagemagick convert errors in php `exec()`?

```
exec('convert img.jpg -resize 100x100 img.jpg',$output);
var_dump($output);
```

`$output` always return a blank array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `exec`, evaluate the return status; which is the third parameter.

```php
exec('convert img.jpg -resize 100x100 img.jpg',$output,$exit_status);
if( $exit_status !== 0 ) {
  // Error handle here
}
```

However, anything written to [stderr](/questions/tagged/stderr) may not be present in the `$output` array. A better, more flexible, approach would be to use [proc_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) & pipes.

```php
$pipe_handle = array();
$pipe_spec = array(
  array('pipe','r'), // stdin
  array('pipe','w'), // stdout
  array('pipe','w')  // stderr
);

$pid = proc_open('convert img.jpg -resize 100x100 img.jpg',$pipe_spec,$pipe_handle);
// Close stdin
fclose($pipe_handle[0]);
// Read what's in stdout buffer & close
$pipe_stdout = stream_get_contents($pipe_handle[1]);
fclose($pipe_handle[1);
// Read what's in stderr buffer & close
$pipe_stderr = stream_get_contents($pipe_handle[2]);
fclose($pipe_handle[2]);

// Get exist status
$exit_status = proc_close($pid);

if( $exit_status === -1 ) {
  // Handle error and evaluate stderr
} else {
  // Handle success and evaluate stdout
}
```

A bit more work, but can cleanly seperate errors from normal messages (if any)